# Split json into separate objects

Tags: json, node.js

I am using node.js to receive hundreds of data objects from an external API in JSON such as below:

```
[
{
"ID": "6548532",
"Status": "active",
"Updated": "2014-11-24T07:32:04-07:00",
"created": "2014-09-15T19:42:37-07:00",
"URL": "www.example.com",
"Categories": [
  "cat-a",
  "cat-b"
],
"Price": "10.00"
},
{
"ID": "8558455",
"Status": "inactive",
"Updated": "2014-10-24T07:32:04-07:00",
"created": "2014-09-15T19:42:37-07:00",
"URL": "www.example.com",
"Categories": [
  "cat-c",
  "cat-r"
],
"Price": "20.00"
}
....
]
```

I would like to separate out the objects so that I can write only objects which have `"Status": "active"` to my database. I am aware that I can do this using string operations before using `JSON.parse` but I am wondering if there is a better way to split up a JSON file into the objects it contains and leave them in an array which I can then process.

Comment: You said it yourself - use `JSON.parse`, there, now you've got an array of objects.  What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realised JSON.parse returned an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you parse the JSON into a Javascript object, you can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to remove the elements where `"Status"` does not equal `"active"`:

```
var responseArray = JSON.parse(responseData),
    filteredArray = responseArray.filter(
       function (obj) {
          return obj.Status == "active";
       });

// Use filteredArray
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not use string operations for this, or do anything to it before parsing it with `JSON.parse`, unless you feel like writing your own complete JSON parsing logic.

Just parse it and then remove the objects that don't have `Status: "active"`:

```
var objects = JSON.parse(JSON_data);
var filtered_objects = objects.filter(function(el) {return (el["Status"] == "active");});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the array returned by `JSON.parse`:

```
var objects = JSON.parse(input);
objects.filter(function (el) {
  return el.status === "active";
});
```